# Landscape mode ios, swift, xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How I can activate landscape mode in Swift, xCode?

I want that all my application is see in landscape mode.

Thanks

Comment: In Device Orientation Check for Landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has a nice [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2244/_index.html) on it, with pictures and full walkthrough.
Basically you need to enable landscape mode in Xcode:

[image]

Comment: How I can make for the photos and the camera reel open in landscape mode?